# Maximum value of line integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I was looking at the following problem:

Among all smooth simple closed curve $C$ oriented counterclockwise find the maximum value of

$$\int_{C} (4x^2y+y^3)dx+(x^3+4x-xy^2)dy$$.

My question is how to approach this type of problem?

Comment: Isn't this just a standard variational problem? I would parametrize  the curve by $(x(t),y(t))$ and use the Euler-Lagrange equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have function $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ such that $x(0) = x(1) = x_0$ and $y(0) = y(1) = y_0$--a closed curved.  This gives $dy = \dot{y}dt$ and $dx = \dot{x}dt$, giving the following integral:

$$
\int\limits_0^1 \left(\left(4x^2y + y^3\right)\dot{x} + \left(x^3 + 4x - xy^2\right)\dot{y}\right)dt
$$

We need to find two functions.  In a sense, we treat this as two "separate" calculus of variations problems.  We simply get more than one Euler-Lagrange equation(see [**Several functions of one variable**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation#Several_functions_of_one_variable)):

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{x}}\right) - \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x} = 0\\
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{y}}\right) - \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial y} = 0
$$

So now we have to find all of the partials...:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x} = & 8xy\dot{x} + \left(3x^2 + 4 - y^2\right)\dot{y} \\
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial y} = & \left(4x^2 + 3y^2\right)\dot{x} -2xy\dot{y}\\
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{x}}=& 4x^2y + y^3\\
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{y}}=& x^3 + 4x - xy^2 \\
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{x}}\right)=& 8xy\dot{x} + 4x^2\dot{y} + 3y^2\dot{y} \\
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{y}}\right) = &3x^2\dot{x} + 4\dot{x} - y^2\dot{x} - 2xy\dot{y}
\end{align}

This gives:

\begin{align}
0 = & x^2\dot{y} + 4y^2\dot{y} - 4\dot{y}\\
0 = & -x^2\dot{x} + 4\dot{x} - 4y^2\dot{x} \\
\rightarrow \\
0 = & \left(x^2 + 4y^2 - 4\right)\dot{y}\\
0 = & \left(x^2 + 4y^2 - 4\right)\dot{x}
\end{align}

By setting $x^2 + 4y^2 - 4 = 0$, we satisfy the equations regardless of $\dot{x}$ or $\dot{y}$, this *gives* the curve--an ellipse:

$$
\frac{x^2}{2^2} + y^2 = 1
$$

We can use:

\begin{align}
x(t) = &2\cos(t) \\
y(t) = &\sin(t) \\
dx =& -2\sin(t)dt \\
dy =& \cos(t)dt \\
4x^2y + y^3 =& 4\cos^2(t)\sin(t) + \sin^3(t) \\
x^3 + 4x - xy^2 =& 8\cos^3(t) + 8\cos(t) - 2\cos(t)\sin^2(t) \\
\left(4x^2y + y^3\right)dx + \left(x^3 + 4x - xy^2\right)dy =& -8\cos^2(t)\sin^2(t) - 2\sin^4(t) + \\
&8\cos^4(t) + 8\cos^2(t) - 2\cos^2(t)\sin^2(t) \\
=& 8\cos^4(t) - 2\sin^4(t) - 10\cos^2(t)\sin^2(t) +8\cos^2(t) \\
\end{align}

I can get rid of the $\sin^4(t)$ and $\cos^4(t)$ by doing $\sin^4(t) = \sin^2(t)\left(1 - \cos^2(t)\right)$ and likewise for $\cos^4(t)$:

\begin{align}
\left(4x^2y + y^3\right)dx + \left(x^3 + 4x - xy^2\right)dy = & 16\cos^2(t) - 2\sin^2(t) - 16\cos^2(t)\sin^2(t) \\
=& 8\left(\cos(2t) + 1\right) - \left(1 - \cos(2t)\right) - 4\sin^2(2t) \\
= &7\cos(2t) - 2\left(1 - \sin(4t)\right) \\
=& 7\cos(2t) + 2\sin(4t) - 2
\end{align}

sine is an odd function and we can choose *any* interval we like (which could be $-\pi \leq t \leq \pi$)--an odd interval.  Choosing this interval, the sine part will give zero leaving:

$$
\int \limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left(7\cos(2t) + 2\sin(4t) - 2\right)dt = \left.\frac{7}{2}\sin(2t) - 2 \right|_{-\pi}^{\pi} = -4\pi
$$

If a maximum exists, it must be $-4\pi$.  The Euler-Lagrange equations don't guarantee a maximum or a minimum--only an extremum.  This *is* the only critical point thus if there *is* a maximum, this is it and no minimum exists and if *there is* a minimum, then this is it, and no maximum exists.

Note that in general, you have:

$$
\oint \left(f(x, y)dx + g(x, y)dy\right)
$$

In terms of calculus of variations, this gives:

$$
\oint \mathcal{L}dt = \oint \left(f(x, y)\dot{x} + g(x, y)\dot{y}\right)dt
$$

Which then leads to the Euler-Lagrange equations:

$$
\left.\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right(f(x, y)\right) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\dot{x} - \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\dot{y} = 0 \\
\left.\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right(g(x, y)\right) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\dot{x} - \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\dot{y} = 0 \\
\leadsto \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\dot{x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\dot{y} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\dot{x} - \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\dot{y} = 0 \\
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\dot{x} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\dot{y} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\dot{x} - \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\dot{y} = 0 \\
\leadsto \\
\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\right)\dot{y} = 0 \\
\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)\dot{x}= 0 
$$

Leading, finally, to:

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = 0
$$

Comment: I would check my work--I'm not overly confident.  I'll correct any mistakes (hopefully none are catastrophic).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Actually I didn't know about the Lagrange-Euler equations so your answer is very enlightening. Even if there are mistakes never mind. The argument is clearly explained.

Answer (score 2):

Use green's theorem. Denote $D$ the interior area of $C$.

By Green's theorem we get that the line integral is equal to 
$$ \int -x^2 - 4y^2 \rm{d}x \rm{d}y + 4 \int 1 \rm{d}x \rm{d}y $$ 
So the idea is whenever we are integrating in an area where $-x^2 -4y^2 \leq -1$ we lose.

Therefore the best thing we can do is pick $C$ to be $ x^2 +4y^2 = 1$. And compute.